# Что означают следующие ANSI escape последовательности?

Tags: c, linux, escape

Просмотрел несколько источников, в том числе англоязычных, но нигде не нашел расшифровку следующих escape-последовательностей:

`\e[%i%d;%dr` (В библиотеке `S-lang` присваивается переменной с именем`Scroll_R_Str`)

`\e[%i%d;%dH` (Тут 3 аргумента, но для установки позиции, согласно документации, используется 2, я не понял этого момента..., в библиотеке `S-lang` данная последовательность присваивается переменной с именем`Abs_Curs_Pos_Str`)

```
\e[P
\e[%dM
\e[%dL
```

Обновлено: неизвестны для меня также следующие последовательности (первые две, насколько я понимаю, не являются ESC-последовательностями, так ли это?)

```
\016
\017
\e(B\e)0
```

Помогите пожалуйста в них разобраться и понять, что они делают?

Comment: Приведите кусочки кода библиотеки (или примеров ее использования) с этими `Abs_Curs_Pos_Str` и `Scroll_R_Str` -- может догадаемся, почему такие форматы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите `man console_codes` или то же самое [в сети](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) или [по-русски](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=console_codes&category=4&russian=0). С ESC[ начинаются CSI-последовательности.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите тут: http://www.opennet.ru/docs/BSD/pascal/syscons/ansi.html

Нашел там `Esc[nM`, `Esc[nL` - удалить / вставить n строк

В английской википедии, вроде норм расписан принцип https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

```
int i, j;
qDebug() << std::sscanf("12345", "%i%d", &i, &j) << i << j;
```

выводит 1, 12345, 0

```
qDebug() << std::sscanf("12 345", "%i%d", &i, &j) << i << j;
```

выводит 2, 12, 345.
Может чем поможет

Comment: Спасибо большое! Второй блок последовательностей стал понятен. Принцип мне их ясен и как работают тоже. Вызывает непонимание 3 аргумента в первых двух последовательностях, хотя даже первые два не разделены пробелом (если бы первым был "символ режима"). Осталось понять первые две последовательности, как они работают и что делают...

Comment: @MaximGusev, меня даже больше смущает отсутствие `;` между `%i` и `%d`. Может там 2 цифры подряд имеются в виду? Ну или цифра+еще что-то. И `<ESC>[P` я вообще нигде не нашел.

Comment: Получается, для парсера это будет одно число, если так написано, но зачем так делать? Почему не одно число, почему разные типы... Хотя типы различные только для scanf. Зачем задавать количество десятков и единиц в числе разными переменными. \e[P - при обущенном аргументе это, как я понимаю, удаление одного символа в строке (но я тогда не знаю из конца или начала - это я прочитал по Вашей же ссылке)

Comment: @MaximGusev я, откровенно говоря, вообще не понимаю, как сработает `scanf` с форматом `%i%d`.